# How do I fix "when" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: editing

I was editing an essay and the sentence checker  said, " 'when' at the beginning of a sentence usually requires a 2nd clause."  I followed some of suggestions it made and it said it was wrong.

Comment: What is the sentence?  We can't really advise in the abstract.

Comment: Does this solve your issue?  https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/can-you-begin-a-sentence-with-when.52251/#:~:text=Of%20course%20you%20can%20start,I%20was%20having%20a%20shower.

Comment: I cannot provide advice unless you can provide me with the sentence which caused the computer spell checker to output an error message.

Answer (score 1):

### Sentence-Checkers are flawed tools.

at least those used for the English language. They can flag correct sentences as containing an error, because they use a form of Bayesian belief networks to assess the probability that a sentence contains an error based on the words in the sentence and their order.

This is because English is not strictly rules-based. The rules of English are guidelines, really. Or rather, most rules in English have exceptions. And those exceptions follow other rules, which also have exceptions. It is because of how the English language evolved -- with Europeans constantly invading each and ruling their neighboring European peoples for a few centuries before getting kicked out.

In your case, it is likely that you've started a sentence with the word 'when' which usually means the sentence is a question and not a statement.  When 'when' is not considered to signal some form of an interrogative is when 'when' is used as a conditional clause -- e.g. When you use 'when', you can confuse simple-minded sentence checkers.

As you can see, in the previous paragraph, you don't have to use two clauses if a sentence starts with 'when', but statistically speaking it will. And sentence-checks rely on statistics.

Comment: Could also be an answer to a "When?" question: "When did you retire?" - "When I managed to sell my company."